# Is there a simple way to visualize a spreadsheet in terminal or as clear text?

Tags: command-line, text, libreoffice

I want to be able to easily show a simple text-only representation of a spreadsheet (Calc or Excel) via the command line (so I can pipe that output to usual Linux text manipulation tools). Is there a tool or quick way of accomplishing that?

Here's an example of how such output could look like:

```
A       B       C       D       E  
Sales   Month  
1000    Jan  
5000    Feb
8000    Mar
2300    Total
```

Comment: Does it have to open .ods?   There is this, [link](http://www.syntax-k.de/projekte/teapot/) but I've never used it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use **unoconv** to transform the Calc sheet into csv. But unoconv seems to be quite instable, i didn't manage to get it working on a simple ods (calc) file.

A better choice is **[jodconverter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter)**. It's available in universe, so you can install it using `apt`. Jodconverter requires an instance of openoffice running and listening on port 8100.

To "manually" convert this sheet

[image: sheet]

from ods to csv:

```
$ soffice -headless -accept="socket,port=8100;urp;"
$ jodconverter Untitled1.ods Untitled1.csv
```

The resulting csv will look like this:

```
$ cat Untitled1.csv 
"A","B","C","D"
34,68,23,3
34234,68468,34,1
3423,6846,34,34535
```

If you don't need the table structure but just the contents for indexing purposes, take a look at **odt2txt**. It seems to be able to handle ods files, too, but it won't preserve the table structure. It doesn't require q soffice process running. With the sheet shown above, you will receive the following output:

```
$ odt2txt Untitled1.ods 

A

B

C

D

34

23

3

34234

3

34

1

3423

234

34

34535
```

Comment: I has hoping to be able to show it as tabular data _directly (without an intermediate .csv), but there's probably no tool for that. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Sure. It's called, save as CSV and use `cat`.